# Word for a dry laugh

Tags: single-word-requests, phrasing

I'm looking for a word to fill in this blank:

> “They’re delinquents,” The doctor agrees. “But, don’t worry, we’re finding them, Jannie. You will get the justice you deserve.”
>
> I let out a _______. “Don’t even try to pretend you’re doing this for me, my husband, or anyone else but yourself. You’re just trying to save your own skin."

I'm looking for a specific type of laugh, where it's a scoff that turns into a chuckle. For example, if a mother has a very rambunctious child, and he/she does something that surprises and angers her at the same time, she might do this kind of laugh. **Is there a word for this?** I don't want to say "dry laugh" or "sarcastic laugh" because there is a bit more too it than those. If there isn't a word for this, is there any other phrases I could use?

Comment: Find the onomatopoeia for the snort, guffaw, heh heh, etc that *you* think conveys the sense you want.

Comment: Are looking more for an adjective describing the laughter or an onomatopoeia or single word for a specific kind of laughter?

Comment: @Helmar  Either works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider ***[sardonic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sardonic)***.

> (adj.) showing that you disapprove of or do not like someone or something : showing disrespect or scorn for someone or something

[Merriam-Webster]

In your usage,

> ..
>
> I let out a ***sardonic laugh***. “Don’t even try to pretend you’re doing this for me, my husband, or anyone else but yourself. You’re just trying to save your own skin."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a snicker.

> Give a smothered or half-suppressed laugh; snigger

https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snicker#snicker__2

Answer (score 1):

I would use the word "scoff" because it seems to express some kind of disbelief.

Comment: Agreed. This would probably change the format from `I let out a scoff` to `I scoffed`.

Answer (score 0):

I would describe a brief, derisive laugh as a "snort".